# An issue with formulas typesetting in Grid & Column

Tags: formatting, grid-layouts

I tried to construct a small sheet with text and equations presented in a convenient publishing form, using `Column`:

```
Column[{
   Row[{"An integral:"}],
   Row[{Integrate[f[x], x]}]
}] // TraditionalForm
```

But every time the integral sign appears in one of expressions inside the `Column`, *Mathematica* reduces its size in the output. In this particular case the output looks like

[image: Integral sign size is reduced in Column]

Without the `Column` (or `Grid`, which seems to have the same effect) wrapper, the integral sign looks convenient:

```
Row[{Integrate[f[x], x]}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: The integral sign has the appropriate size when it does not appear as the content of Column or Grid]

I tried to add `Pane` wrapper to the `Column` contents, and played with `ItemSize` option too, with no effect. Actually, I can't even figure out what exactly happens within the `Column` (or `Grid`) function that reduces the `\[Integral]` size.

So, the question is: what causes the shrinking in `Column` and `Grid`, and is there a way to control it?

I was thinking of using `GraphicsGrid` instead, but it seems look more like a hack than a proper solution — if it would help at all.

Notes:

1. You can notice the same effect in a Standard Form too, it is just more clear in the Traditional output.
2. I'm using *Mathematica* 8 on Windows 7 Basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that Column by default is setting the integral in the `InlineFormula` style. If you force it to use the `DisplayFormula` style, the integral will be set larger.

```
Column[{Row[{"An integral:"}], 
        Row[{Style[Integrate[f[x], x], "DisplayFormula"]}]}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I missed the intent of the question.  Nice solution.

Comment: Yes, that does it! Thanks. Mathematica 8 Documentation Center is almost silent when it comes to keywords `InlineFormula` and `DisplayFormula`. :-\

Comment: Clarification, Do the uses of Row[] and TraditionalForm do anything in this?  Just wondering.

Comment: No, they don't matter. But I think that leaving Rows in the example makes sense because I could use some inline formulas in the sheet, and they'd look OK, while the standalone formulae and calculations need the `DisplayFormula` option, and it's only needed in the corresponding Rows.

Comment: @Jagra. `TraditionalForm` is innocent -- `Row` is under suspicion.

Comment: @m_goldberg I've checked it, the formula is still Inline without Rows.

Comment: So I guess that Column is the guilty party after all.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes; and it's all the same with `Grid`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `AllowScriptLevelChange -> False` as an option to `Column` (however I'm not sure if there's such an option in Mathematica 8. I'm running version 11.3)

Compare these two outputs:

```
Column[{
   Row[{"An integral:"}],
   Row[{Integrate[f[x], x]}]
}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Column[{
   Row[{"An integral:"}],
   Row[{Integrate[f[x], x]}]
}, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Although it works in 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit), but there's a warning on the `AllowScriptLevelChange` help page:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [`AllowScriptLevelChange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllowScriptLevelChange) as suggested by @roman addresses the main issue you are encountering. Another possibility is to set the script level directly using [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style), in which case the script level change requested by [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column)/[`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid) is ignored:

```
Column[{
    Row[{"An integral:"}],
    Style[Row[{Integrate[f[x], x]}], ScriptLevel->0]
}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Column[{"An integral:", TextCell[TraditionalForm[Integrate[f[x], x]], FontSize -> 24]}]
```

[image]

A slight variation, this works too:

```
Column[{"An integral:", TraditionalForm[Integrate[f[x], x]]}, 
 ItemStyle -> {2 -> FontSize -> 24}]
```

[image]
Isolating the individual pieces often helps in controlling different kinds of formatting.

Comment: I see this http://i.stack.imgur.com/H27aQ.png

Comment: @belisarius -- That looks odd.  I probably have an artifact, like f[] previously defined.  I'll correct and update.  Ah, that does it.  Thx

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my post, but it's not the formula size that bothers me, it's just the integral symbol size: `\[Integral]`, or “∫”. I could just write `Style[Integrate[f[x], x], FontSize -> 24]` instead of `Integrate[f[x], x]` in the original code, and get the larger sized formula. But I have to write something like `Row[{DisplayForm@
   AdjustmentBox[Style["\[Integral]", Large], 
    BoxBaselineShift -> 1/2], f[x], "\[ThinSpace]", Dt[x]}]` (aligning manually on the box level) to get the result closer to my 2nd pic of (sole) integral which is what I expect to see in the sheet.